# bootable WIN10 USB stick created under ubuntu results in black screen

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows-10

I want to get a dual boot setup with ubuntu 18 and windows 10. I am currently running ubuntu 16.04. My plan was to first install win 10 then install ubuntu 18 over the old ubuntu version.

I created a bootable usb stick following the instructions given in thie follwing question and answer: [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu/487970#487970)

I create the bootable USB stick using woeUSB, before installing that I created the gpt partition table and then formatted the stick to fat32 as demanded. I then restart the computer, go into BIOS, go to the boot override and boot from the usb. At first I see the windows symbol for waiting (the dots that are moving in a circle), but the dots quickly disappear. Then nothing happens and I stare into a blackscreen.

I tried several ways that are proposed in the answer I mentioned above, yet the only results I achieve are either the one I just described, or the USB stick is not even recognized.

I also tried using mkusb. I also checked the checksum of the win10 iso file. Also, a friend of mine tried to make the same stick bootable under windows, resulting in the same issue as mentioned above. This probably points to the USB stick being incompatible with my laptop, does it?

I do not know what else to do. Thanks a lot in advance for your help!!

Comment: Suggest contacting woeUSB support at https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB/issues

Comment: Try [mkusb version 12 according to this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu/837380#837380) (another answer to the same question). It works for me.

Comment: I just tried using mkusb. Unluckily results in the same black screen. MIght this be a problem of the usb stick I use?
I also created an issue on their github : https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB/issues/195

Comment: Maybe there is a hardware problem, that the USB stick is not compatible with the computer. This is not common, but it happens. You can check by testing with another USB stick or with another computer. See this link (and links from it), [Howto help USB boot drives](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858)

Comment: Did you check (with a checksum) that your Windows iso file was downloaded correctly?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I did the checksum and found no problem there. Also, as I added in the question, a friend tried making the same stick bootable under windows, leading to the same result.  This makes the incompatibility between stick and laptop seem most likely to me. I just ordered a new USB stick, let's see what happens with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out that my problem had to do with my own harddisk. I did have a dual boot before with Windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04. At some point though, weirdly, windows 10 just stopped working. Just couldn't boot it anymore. Since I rarely used it I just left it at that.

This faulty windows10 installation was my problem here though. Only after I formatted the part of the harddisk where Windows10 lay was it possible to get into the installation menu of windows10. At that point all usb sticks I created started working.

Not sure if I should let this question/answer stay on askubuntu, since it seems to be a rather exotic error.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. Even if it is unusual, it will probably help some users in the future :-)